# what exactly is tuple in TStream?

Tags: java, apache-edgent

Here is the code taken from [Apache Edgent Documentation](http://edgent.apache.org/recipes/recipe_adaptable_filter_range.html)

I could not understand what tuple exactly is. The code is given below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TempSensor sensor = new TempSensor();
    DirectProvider dp = new DirectProvider();
    Topology topology = dp.newTopology();

    TStream<Double> tempReadings = topology.poll(sensor, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    TStream<Double> simpleFiltered = tempReadings.filter(tuple ->
            !optimalTempRangeRef.get().contains(tuple));
    simpleFiltered.sink(tuple -> System.out.println("Temperature is out of range! "
            + "It is " + tuple + "\u00b0F!"));

    tempReadings.print();

    dp.submit(topology);
}
```

The error that I get is ***tuple cannot be resolved to a variable***. What exactly is the error that I am getting? Thank you.

Comment: A [nested ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Tuples_as_nested_ordered_pairs).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch please try to justify your answer with respect to my question. Thank you.

Comment: Please ask clear questions. If you get an error always include the full error message, including stacktrace. As you see, people get confused about qhat exactly you are asking and you get answers that don't help much. Avoid that by being more clear. Read [ask], thanks.

Comment: @ArunSubba Please try to justify your evident failure to read the link so kindly provided with respect to your purpose in asking your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TStream<T>` [interface](https://edgent.apache.org/javadoc/r1.2.0/org/apache/edgent/topology/TStream.html) is designed to model a stream of data, typically sensor readings. The `T` in this case is the type used to store an individual reading, but 'reading' really can mean multiple numbers (eg temperature, humidity & windspeed) joined together into a single composite type, which generically is referred to here as a 'tuple' of values.

However, looking at the context of your example, we're dealing with a stream of simple temperature readings, so here `T` corresponds to a single number of type `Double`. So the choice of 'tuple' as a variable name is a bit confusing (mathematically, it's a *1-tuple*, but in this case that just means 'a number').

In your code, the `filter()` method takes a [predicate](https://edgent.apache.org/javadoc/r1.2.0/org/apache/edgent/function/Predicate.html), which here is

```
tuple -> !optimalTempRangeRef.get().contains(tuple)
```

And `optimalTempRangeRef.get()` returns a `Range(Double)`, so the predicate is saying *"is our temperature value outside our optimal range?"*

From the docs for `Range`:

```
contains() is used to check for containment: e.g.

 Ranges.closed(2,4).contains(2);    // returns true
 Ranges.open(2,4).contains(2);      // returns false
 Ranges.atLeast(2).contains(2);     // returns true
 Ranges.greaterThan(2).contains(2); // returns false
 Ranges.atMost(2).contains(2);      // returns true
 Ranges.lessThan(2).contains(2);    // returns false
```

---

EDIT:

Looks like your IDE is having trouble with the Java 8 lambda syntax, so you can re-write your code using anonymous inner classes, like this:

```
import org.apache.edgent.function.Predicate;
import org.apache.edgent.function.Consumer;


public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    TempSensor sensor = new TempSensor();
    DirectProvider dp = new DirectProvider();
    Topology topology = dp.newTopology();

    TStream<Double> tempReadings = topology.poll( sensor, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
    TStream<Double> filteredStream = tempReadings.filter( new Predicate<Double>()
    {
        public boolean test( Double reading )
        {
            return !optimalTempRangeRef.get().contains( reading );
        }
    } );

    filteredStream.sink( new Consumer<Double>()
    {
        public void accept( Double reading )
        {
            System.out.println( "Temperature is out of range! "
                                + "It is " + reading + "\u00b0F!" )
        }
    } );

    tempReadings.print();

    dp.submit( topology );
}
```

Comment: And which version of Java are you compiling against? The `->` syntax is only since Java 8

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still says: The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Double, boolean

Comment: Actually I am using eclipse IDE on Raspberry Pi3 with Raspbian os. I have java version "1.8.0_65".

Comment: Check that your Eclipse project is set to use Java 8 syntax

Comment: I have compiler compliance level of 1.7 which is highest

Comment: Thank you Richard Inglis for your help, it really helped me.

Comment: Richard Inglis could you help me out with [filter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549019/why-isnt-the-filter-method-working?noredirect=1#comment88109818_50549019)