# Why isn't the filter method working?

Tags: java, apache, apache-edgent

As given in the [docs of Apache Edgent](http://edgent.apache.org/recipes/recipe_value_out_of_range.html)  I tried to filter out my sensor  readings wherein the values of the temperature sensor must lie in between 80  to 85 F.

But when I tried connecting my sensor the readings were 75F and no  message was shown like: *temperature is out of range*.

Is it that the filter  method isn't working? if so please try help me out. thanks.

the range values are set as:

```
static double OPTIMAL_TEMP_LOW = 80.0;
static double OPTIMAL_TEMP_HIGH = 85.0;
static Range<Double> optimalTempRange = Ranges.closed(OPTIMAL_TEMP_LOW, OPTIMAL_TEMP_HIGH);
```

The sensor object is `TempSensor ts`

```
TempSensor ts = new TempSensor();
Stream<Double> temp = top.poll(ts, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

the filtering part:

```
TStream<Double> simpleFiltered = temp.filter(tuple ->
tuple < OPTIMAL_TEMP_LOW || tuple > OPTIMAL_TEMP_HIGH);
simpleFiltered.sink(tuple -> System.out.println("Temperature is out of range! "
+ "It is " + tuple + "\u00b0F!"));

/*TStream<Double> simpleFiltered = temp.filter(tuple ->
        !optimalTempRange.contains(tuple));
simpleFiltered.sink(tuple -> System.out.println("Temperature is out of range! "
            + "It is " + tuple + "\u00b0F!"));*/

// See what the temperatures look like
simpleFiltered.print();

dp.submit(top);
```

output:

```
Selet a port:
1: ttyACM0 Port opened succesefully.
7373.40
73.40
73.40 ...
```

[image: the output]

Comment: what happened when you used "optimalTempRange" ? (it's been commented out)

Comment: @mangusta the output remains same.

Comment: please check the answer below and give a feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that happened because your filter and sink have been assigned to another TStream object, not the one you are printing out.
Probably you need to try this:

```
TempSensor ts = new TempSensor();
TStream<Double> temp = top.poll(ts, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).filter(tuple ->
tuple < OPTIMAL_TEMP_LOW || tuple > OPTIMAL_TEMP_HIGH);
temp.sink(tuple -> System.out.println("Temperature is out of range! "
+ "It is " + tuple + "\u00b0F!"));

// See what the temperatures look like
temp.print();

dp.submit(top);
```

Comment: @Arun Subba in any case you probably agree that a filtered stream should be printed instead of "temp" : )

Comment: how about assigning a filter back to "temp" instead of "simpleFiltered"?

Comment: temp = temp.filter(tuple ->
    tuple < OPTIMAL_TEMP_LOW || tuple > OPTIMAL_TEMP_HIGH);

Comment: temp.sink(tuple -> System.out.println("Temperature is out of range! "
    + "It is " + tuple + "\u00b0F!"));

Comment: it says duplicate local variable temp.

Comment: @Arun Subba please have a look at the updated answer

Comment: by the way, are you sure that "filter" method filters out the tuples satisfying its argument predicate OR oppositely, the tuples that satisfy the predicate actually REMAIN?

Comment: if they remain, you would have to use the opposite predicate: tuple ->
tuple >= OPTIMAL_TEMP_LOW && tuple <= OPTIMAL_TEMP_HIGH

Comment: The results are same unfortunately.

Comment: @Arun Subba have you tried using the opposite predicate that I suggested in previous comment?

Comment: @Arun Subba just for sake of clarity, are you sure you compiled the code prior to running the app?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your code matches the example in the documentation, but it looks as if we’re creating a filtered stream, and then ignoring it in `temp.print()`.

You could try changing that line to `simpleFiltered.print()`

Comment: Sorry, I got nothing else

Comment: could there be any possibility that the hardware (sensor readings delay) and the code (java code) is not synchronized properly?

Comment: @Arun Subba your Java program gets a stream of values sooner or later, and processes them accordingly. It's not about synchronization

Comment: @Arun Subba the strangest thing is that even though you tried completely opposite predicates for the stream filter, you still get the same output (according to your words). I bet you miss something out there

Comment: are the values received from stream automatically typecasted to the type declared in TStream<>? (in your case, "Double")

Comment: @mangusta Thank you for your time and effort. I found the mistake which was not in the code that we tried to figure it out it was on the `get()` method of the `TempSensor` class which had a `while` loop which was continuously printing the received data lol. :)